# Symfony 2.1 Vagrant vs. Amazon

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, symfony-2.1

I have a Symfony 2.0 site running via a vagrant machine and then also deployed to an Amazon EC2 instance. Recently I decided to upgrade to Symfony 2.1. This worked fine in the vagrant machine but when I deploy the code to the Amazon Server is does not work right. The main site is displayed and then when I login to the "user" portion of the site the screen goes white. I have no errors in the logs or any indication of what is wrong. Mind you this works perfectly in vagrant.

I did have an issue with annotations for prePersist and preUpdate on the Amazon server as well with Symfony 2.1 where it could not load the @ORM/annotations, but I changed those to PrePersist and PreUpdate and that fixed the problem with that. Now I have a white screen after logging in and am curious if Symfony 2.1 may not be autoloading the classes like it should be?

Any Ideas wold be greatly appreciated?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have logging enabled on the Amazon machine and does the server have write access to the `app/logs` directory. I had recently a whitescreen of death and didn't see any errors in the log because of that. However, that was not on an Amazon machine.

Comment: Yes it does. I would also assume it to not work at all if it did't have write access. But it works until a user logs in. And only on Symfony 2.1 on the Amazon Server.

Comment: Do you have the same OS versions, PHP versions, installed extensions, etc. between the machines?

Comment: That's the weird part they are exactly the same...